# Setting up Celery with Django without any SQL

Tags: django, mongodb, celery, django-celery

I have a **Django** app running on **Gunicorn/Gevent**, without any SQL database.  I don't use Django's ORM at all, my database is **mongoDB**, using the **mongoengine** ORM.  I would like to use **Celery** for asynchronous tasks, using **mongoDB as the broker**, but the recommended way to do this with Django is to install **django-celery**, which seems to rely on "regular" SQL models.  I would like to avoid having to install and maintain a SQL database just for that.

**What's the recommended way to use Celery in Django *without* relying on any SQL models?**
Ideally, I would love a port of django-celery for mongoDB, for example.

I guess I could follow the Celery instructions for non-django python code, but I'm not sure where and how to load the config, and how it will interact with wsgi / gunicorn / gevent.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: FYI, I've used celery with tornado, and this [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) helped a lot - basically you'll have `tasks.py` with your tasks, `celeryconfig.py` with your celery configuration and may be `supervisord.conf` for managing celery worker processes.